# Assign values in a for loop using R

Tags: r, for-loop, data.table

all:

The problem came when I tried to use `for` loop to create 5 dataframes and assign these five dataframes to a list. Please see an example:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(123)    
df <- as.data.table(list(rnorm(10,1,1), rnorm(10,1,1)))
list <- list() 
for(i in 2011:2015){
             list[[paste0("A_",i)]] <- df[, year := as.numeric(i)]
             }
```

So, as I expected, the value of `year` variable should be as same as `i` in each element. For example, value of `year` in `list[1]` should be 2011. However, the above code returns 2015 for `year` in all elements:

```
    > list[1]
$A_2011
            V1         V2 year
 1:  0.4395244  2.2240818 2015
 2:  0.7698225  1.3598138 2015
 3:  2.5587083  1.4007715 2015
 4:  1.0705084  1.1106827 2015
 5:  1.1292877  0.4441589 2015
 6:  2.7150650  2.7869131 2015
 7:  1.4609162  1.4978505 2015
 8: -0.2650612 -0.9666172 2015
 9:  0.3131471  1.7013559 2015
10:  0.5543380  0.5272086 2015
```

I can't figure out what's wrong with my code. I would appreciate if anyone could point out the problem here. I would like to see any other solutions using `lapply` or so, if any. Many thanks!

Comment: Quick fix: Add `list[[paste0("A_",i)]]$year <- i` in your loop.

Comment: Generally a lot less painful to keep it in one table, like `yrs = 2011:2015;
res <- df[rep(1:.N, length(yrs))][, year := rep(yrs, each = nrow(df))][]` or `df[, rbindlist(Map(cbind, .(.SD), year = yrs))]`

Comment: @Majo The fix works! However, I really want to know why my code does not work as expected. I think the logic is correct there.

Comment: @Frank Thanks! What a beautiful solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> for(i in 2011:2015){
>   list[[paste0("A_",i)]] <- df[, year := as.numeric(i)]
> }
> ```
>
> I would appreciate if anyone could point out the problem here.

`<-` makes a pointer to the same data.table, `df`, instead of making a copy. Wrapping this in `copy()` should fix that. However, it's cleaner to work with a single big table:

```
yrs = 2011:2015
res <- df[, rbindlist(Map(cbind, .(.SD), year = yrs))]
```

This has a couple advantages:

- Lists of data.tables run into weird issues with pointers.
- A big data.table allows one to use `by=` to iterative over subtables, which can be a lot more efficient.

Comment: Clear enough! Thank you @Frank

Answer (score 1):

This worked:
Using dplyr to append the new column as opposed to above:

```
setNames(lapply(2011:2015, function(i){
    as.data.table(list(rnorm(10,1,1), rnorm(10,1,1))) %>% 
        mutate(year = i)
}), sprintf("A_%s", 2011:2015))
```

### Edit for seed handling :

```
setNames(lapply(2011:2015, function(i){
    set.seed(123)
    as.data.table(list(rnorm(10,1,1), rnorm(10,1,1))) %>% 
        mutate(year = i)
}), sprintf("A_%s", 2011:2015))
```

### Output:

```
List of 5
 $ A_2011:'data.frame': 10 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ V1  : num [1:10] 0.44 0.77 2.56 1.07 1.13 ...
  ..$ V2  : num [1:10] 2.224 1.36 1.401 1.111 0.444 ...
  ..$ year: int [1:10] 2011 2011 2011 2011 2011 2011 2011 2011 2011 2011
 $ A_2012:'data.frame': 10 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ V1  : num [1:10] 0.44 0.77 2.56 1.07 1.13 ...
  ..$ V2  : num [1:10] 2.224 1.36 1.401 1.111 0.444 ...
  ..$ year: int [1:10] 2012 2012 2012 2012 2012 2012 2012 2012 2012 2012
 $ A_2013:'data.frame': 10 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ V1  : num [1:10] 0.44 0.77 2.56 1.07 1.13 ...
  ..$ V2  : num [1:10] 2.224 1.36 1.401 1.111 0.444 ...
  ..$ year: int [1:10] 2013 2013 2013 2013 2013 2013 2013 2013 2013 2013
 $ A_2014:'data.frame': 10 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ V1  : num [1:10] 0.44 0.77 2.56 1.07 1.13 ...
  ..$ V2  : num [1:10] 2.224 1.36 1.401 1.111 0.444 ...
  ..$ year: int [1:10] 2014 2014 2014 2014 2014 2014 2014 2014 2014 2014
 $ A_2015:'data.frame': 10 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ V1  : num [1:10] 0.44 0.77 2.56 1.07 1.13 ...
  ..$ V2  : num [1:10] 2.224 1.36 1.401 1.111 0.444 ...
  ..$ year: int [1:10] 2015 2015 2015 2015 2015 2015 2015 2015 2015 2015
```

Comment: Thank you! Using dplyr is definitely another good way to go. But do you know why my code does not work as expected?

Comment: Sadly I'm not as well versed as I would like to be with data.table to explain more clearly